# How to keep top panel only on only one of my dual monitors?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, panel

I am using dual monitors (equal) and have recently switched to 11.10.  When I used 10.04, the top panel with indicators, etc. was showing only on my left monitor, leaving the entire space of the right monitor available for app windows.

In 11.10, the top panel is duplicated on the second monitor. IMO, it makes no good, just wastes precious desktop space.

Is there any way to make the top panel to show only on one monitor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 and the same question - how to make top panel on one screen only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not currently supported, but those things are being discussed, so it's possible that it might become available in some version after 12.04.